# Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'beforeEach' must be of type 'Lifecycle', but here has type 'HookFunction'

Tags: jestjs, mocha.js

```
../../node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts:2581:13 - error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable 'beforeEach' must be of type 'Lifecycle', but here has type 'HookFunction'.

2581 declare var beforeEach: Mocha.HookFunction;
```

I get 7 similar bugs, all in `mocha` and `jest`

I use both packages so uninstalling mocha (`npm uninstall @types/mocha`) won't help

Both `node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts` and `node_modules/truffle_typing/index.d.ts` have an `expect` declared, which causes an error:

`node_modules/truffle_typing/index.d.ts`:

```
 declare const expect: Chai.ExpectStatic;
```

`node_modules/@types/jest/index.d.ts`:

```
declare const expect: jest.Expect;
```

One thing worked out: I added the following property to the `tsconfig` file. It solves the problem but it looks a bit hacky and I don’t like to skip any checks that are set in Typescript by default.

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "skipLibCheck": true   },
```

EDIT:

As I encountered the error with Mocha types, I copied the `index.d.ts` file from the `node_modules/@types/mocha` folder and put it in the newly created `overrides/mocha directory`. In the overrides/jest folder I created an empty `index.d.ts`. Then I added one new option to my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": ["overrides", "node_modules/@types"]
    }
}
```

Versions:

```
"@types/jest": "20.0.6",
"@types/mocha": "5.2.5",
"jest": "22.4.3",
"mocha": "5.2.0"
```